# Make voip push notification work again on iOS 13

Tags: voip, ios13

As per documentation from Apple (at WWDC session ["Advances in App Background Execution"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/)), "Repeatedly failing to report calls may prevent your app from receiving any more incoming call notifications." so in this case ,

1) How can we find out wether my app stop receiving any more incoming call notifications? is this data will present anywhere in console?

2) How can we do that work again?

One of my application stop receiving the voip notification from last week. Now i have updated my code base as per the documentation but still i am not getting any Voip notification.

Answer (score -3):

You can follow this , we also had the same problem. The solution is here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot find a solution from your link. Can you show me more detail?
My problem is, my app is no longer receive voip push, so didReceiveIncomingPushWith will not be triggered

Comment: According to new Apple documentation you need to call `reportNewIncomingCall(with:update:completion:)` right after receiving a VOIP notification in a very short amount of time, Not doing so will result your app ban to receive more voip notifications in the future. To re establish relation with voip you need to reinstall the application. Apple is forcing developers to report a call after voip, just to prevent abusive behaviour of voip notification.

Comment: "reinstall the application" is a big problem. I cannot tell my user to uninstall app and then reinstall it.

Comment: Well developer should adopt beta versions for ios13 before then public release. So I think there is not a way to solve this issue, but did you actually tried to reinstall on your device to see is this true that now is it working?

Comment: Yeah of course I tried it, if I reinstall it, it's a new app on device so no problem with receiving voip push

Comment: @MudassirZulfiqar Apple _must_ provide a way to fix this without reinstalling the app. And that's what people are looking for. I can't tell customers "you have to reinstall the app", I have to fix it without reinstall.

Comment: Downvoted because you can't respond to push notifications once you stop getting them.